# Matching increasing numbers

Tags: javascript

I need to match numbers in the strings in an array.

```
['peter1','peter2','peter4'] ==> [1,2,0]
```

I want to regex each string of the array `/1/g` for the first string, `/2/g` for the second string and so forth.

Comment: What if the string has multiple numbers separated by non-numbers, eg `"peter1peter2"`?

Comment: Each string will only have one number

Comment: How does `peter4` map to `0`?

Comment: Theres no 3 in it , cause it's position 3

Comment: This question is a little bit confusing. Can you explain what your expected output should be?

Comment: *Each string will only have one number* And will **always** have one number? Will `peter10` in the first position match, or not?

Comment: One number as in one digit number

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regexp for this--you're just looking to see if the string contains the index, which you can check with `indexOf` or `includes`.

```js
const inputs = ['peter1','peter2','peter4'];

const output = inputs.map((str, i) => str.includes(i + 1) ? i + 1 : 0)

console.log(output);
```

Comment: What if the first string is `peter10`?

Comment: @Phil Good point, but the OP did say for the first element he wants to match `/1/g`, which is what this does.

Comment: OP just confirmed, *"One number as in one digit number"*. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use a map function to...

1. Extract the number via regex
2. Compare it with the current 1-based index to filter out-of-sync numbers to `0`.

```js
const a = ['peter1','peter2','peter4']

const b = a.map((s, i) => parseInt(/\d+/.exec(s).pop()) === i + 1 ? i + 1 : 0)

console.info(b)
```

Comment: @torazaburo sorry to revert your edit (I was in the middle of adding more info). Anyway, OP says (and I quote) [*"Each string will only have one number"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647223/matching-increasing-numbers/43647325#comment74342706_43647223)

Comment: `3 & 1 === 1` so if the array has a `"peter3"` as the first item, there will be some issues (and this is just an example).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir damn, I had a feeling something like that would happen. Changed it to a straight comparison

Comment: Now it's purfekt :D!

Comment: Phooey, I was loving the use of `&`.

Comment: @torazaburo Me too :(